# NullPointerException in connecting to mysql using php and in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get a data from URL using some tutorials in connecting to mysql using php.

However, I get a nullpointerexception when I run the code.

**Database_demo.java**

```
 package com.database_demo;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.net.ParseException;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class Database_demo extends ListActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();

    try{

    //http post
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://uragon-dev.com/synergy/webservices.php?action=displayAll");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

    //Convert response to string  
    try
    {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));

      sb = new StringBuilder();

      String line = null;

      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
      {
         sb.append(line + "\n");
      }

      is.close();

      result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //END Convert response to string   
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
               json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
               r.add(json_data.getString("users"));
           }
           setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, r));
        }
        catch(JSONException e1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
 }
```

The error in the logcat points to this line.

```
 try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

Here is the data to fetched on the url http://uragon-dev.com/synergy/webservices.php?action=displayAll

```
{"users":[{"username":"jokerxvier","firstname":"jason","lastname":"javier"},{"username":"migz","firstname":"miguel","lastname":"rivera"}],"success":1}
```

What could be the problem that is causing this? Also I would like to know how can I pass data to the url and not just fetching data from it. Android newbie here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to attempt a network operation on the main thread. Have a look at this post on how to handle this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/2045570

Read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

EDIT:

The reason you are getting a JSON error is because you are catching your first exception: HERE

```
    try{

    //http post
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://uragon-dev.com/synergy/webservices.php?action=displayAll");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
```

So here:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

`result` will always be null. This is your first problem you need to solve. You can't access the network from your main thread.

To see your error message add this line : `e.printStackTrace();` to your catch block and it will print a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` in your logcat output.

Comment: I get these errros in the logcat

`at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
 `

is the json part wrong?

Comment: @MiguelRivera That's exactly what I said it would be. Please read this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/2045570

Comment: so i'm to create a new method like the one given in the link?

Comment: Network on main thread is definitely a issue but that exception added on Android 3.0 or API level 11, so if you run you app on older Android version you will not get networkonMainThread error.

Comment: i'm really a newbie here so any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you said the error is on the `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);`. If this is the case, could you try checking the value of `result`? Maybe use `Log` to display it on the Logcat.

If the error is `NetworkOnMainThread`, you will need to check the answer from @user2045570

Hope this helps, Good luck

Reid

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of issue. JSON you are trying to read is not an array that's an object. So code should be

```
JSONObject result = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray users = result.getJSONArray("users");
```

And, please do not open network connection on main thread.

Comment: I followed your answer and I get these messages on the logcat.

http://shrib.com/logerror

The logcat points to this error. ` HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); `